# Simple SPARQL query of foaf RDF not working

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, foaf

I'm new at semantic web, where I learn basics, but I'm stuck at the beginning.

After reading this link: http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/semantic-university/sparql-by-example, I try some examples by myself, but without success.

For example, using OpenLink Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor http://demo.openlinksw.com/sparql, I put at Default Graph URI this http://njh.me/foaf.rdf and simple query

```
 PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
 select ?name
 where 
 {
 ?person foaf:name ?name .
 }
```

to get name of a person who is owner of this RDF file. Also, if I put following query

```
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
select ?name
where 
{
?OnlineAcount foaf:name ?name .
}
```

nothing is happening.

Where I make mistake?

The same situation is with https://ai.wu.ac.at/~polleres/foaf.rdf, http://richard.cyganiak.de/foaf.rdf for the first query.

Any help at the beginning of my semantic tour will be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below the query input pane, there's an option for **Sponging**.  You need to select the option **Retrieve remote RDF data for all missing source graphs.**   Then you'll get results.  However, the file that you mentioned actually has lots of **foaf:name** triples, not just one for the creator of the file.  You might try **select ?person ?name** to see what else is in that data.